# Delegated approver email notification

Tags: approval-process

I have created an approval process on a custom object. I have also selected "Enable Email Approval Response" checkbox under "Workflow and Approval Process" settings. Everything works fine and approver gets notification email. He can simply approver record by replying back to that email. But the problem is that delegated approver of actual approver doesn't get this email. I need to notify delegated approver since actual approver is going on vacation. Is there any setting that needs to be enabled? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

We came across the same problem and, according to the article below, it's not possible.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000073341&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

This is very much possible, once you select delegated approver, you need to go to the delegated approver's User record and Under Approver  Settings > Receive Approval Request mails picklist has the option:
"If I am approver or delegated approver"

Comment: This is correct. We need to check "Receive Approval Request Emails" for both approver and delegate approver.

Answer (score 0):

In the user record (who is going on vacation), set the new/alternative user as delegate in the Delegated Approver field.

Whoever(alternative/new user) has been set as delegated Approver, go to this new user record and set the Receive Approval Request Emails as 'If I am an Approver or Delegated Approver' to receive emails on getting Approval Request.

Additionally, there's a checkbox on the Approval Steps on the Approval Process that needs to be checked to allow delegated approver to receive the notification and approve. If this is unchecked, after checking this box the delegated approver will start receiving notifications.

refer - https://probablesolution.blogspot.com/2022/04/delegate-approvers.html